# I need suggestion if any one tried Apache HAWQ installation built on top of Quantcast File System (QFS)

Tags: apache, hawq, qfs

I have requirement where need to install Apache HAWQ on top of Quantcast File System (QFS). As I understood Apache HAWQ is installed on top of HDFS. Suggestion / guidance please.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to install Apache HAWQ on QFS ? AFAIK, apache hawq does not support QFS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like QFS also does not support the HDFS API. HAWQ is currently dependent on libhdfs3, hence only filesystems compatible with that API stand a reasonable chance. There is an active [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAWQ-1270) for supporting "pluggable backends" in HAWQ, but it is likely a ways out.

You *might* be able to hack the master and segment installation a bit and expose data on QFS via an [external table](https://hawq.incubator.apache.org/docs/userguide/2.1.0.0-incubating/reference/sql/CREATE-EXTERNAL-TABLE.html) or a PL/Python function. If you decide to pursue this, please open a new JIRA and we can provide more tangible suggestions / example code.